# Search & Replace Null with Value from Select Query (Enter Parameter Value)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created an Update Query that pulls in Type by ID#; however, if there is no match for all IDs, I want to fill in the blank Types using the most common Type identified from a Select Query. How do I do that without using VB (if possible)? Here is what I attempted (Thanks in advance):

1. Update Query 1: Match List of IDs and Types (Table 1) to new list of IDs (Table 2). If there is an ID match, then fill in Type on Table 2 with the match from Table 1.
2. Select Query 1: Identifies all the possibilities of Types on Table 2 and groups them in order of count.
3. Update Query 2: Identify all Nulls under Type in Table 2 and update them with the Type with the highest count in Select Query 1; however, I am receiving an Enter Parameter Value error.

Comment: Even if you do not use of prefer SQL View, the best practice when seeking help for queries is to include the SQL in the question.  Otherwise, it makes it very difficult or impossible to identify problems, for instance with parameter errors.  Wordy explanations are not enough for this.  Read the stackexchange help for proper formatting of code.  Edit your question and paste the SQL for each of the three queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick first attempt.  If you post your query SQL, perhaps I could improve upon this.

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET Table2.Type = DLookUp("[Type]","Select Query 1",
   "[CountOfType] = (SELECT Max([CountOfType]) FROM [Select Query 1])")
WHERE (Table2.Type Is Null)
```

*Note 1*: If there are more than one Type value that is most common (i.e. multiple type values have the same count in [Select Query 1]) this solution will randomly select one of them.

*Note 2*: This does not require a separate VBA module nor writing your own VBA function. However, DLookup is an Access Domain Aggregate Function and is not a native SQL function, so technically is called and executed within Access VBA engine. Such functions can be extremely useful and powerful, reducing the number of queries you have to write and maintain to get certain tasks done. It is possible, however, to create a set of additional queries that will accomplish the same task using "pure" SQL.